# Adding levels to a SpriteKit App

Tags: design-patterns, swift, sprite-kit

I'm playing around with spriteKit, and am working on a simple 2d dungeon style game where the hero moves from min-level to mini-level, each represented by a single screen.  Think about the style of [the first Zelda game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda_(video_game)).

Having watched the WWDC videos on spriteKit, especially the Best Practices one from 2014, I've been thinking about the best way to build the game, and it seems to me that the best thing would be to have one "GameScene" class that provides the logic for all the levels, and a set of .sks files, one for each level.  That will let me build design each screen graphically, building in different obstacles, enemy placement, etc. Coupled with some plists, it should let me keep out of hard-coding data in as well.

However, I'm having a devil of a time loading the levels in.  For instance, right now I'm trying to use the following code to trigger a transition between level 1 and level 2.

```
func transitionToLevel2(){
    var level2 = SKScene.unarchiveFromFile("level2") as GameScene
    var transition = SKTransition.pushWithDirection(.Left, duration: 1.0)
    self.scene?.view?.presentScene(level2, transition: transition)

}
```

By my understanding of the extension to SKNode in this stock template's AppDelegate.swift file, this should let load what's in the visual file named level2.sks as an instance of GameScene.  But while it's running, it seems that some sort of exception is fired, and the app pauses to let me know that "Swift dynamic cast failed". level2 loads, but simply as a SKScene, not as a Game Scene.

So, is my code above wrong, or does it just feel that way because I'm using the wrong approach?

I feel like this is a total noob question, but maybe asking it can help some other poor soul who's trying to get their mind wrapped around it.

Comment: Your approach is not wrong and is called the Factory Method Pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). You just need to implement it correctly. How have you handled instantiation in the GameScene class? Post that code here as well.

Comment: That fixed it, Ox141E....if you want to slide it into an answer, I'll accept it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement

```
  var level2 = SKScene.unarchiveFromFile("level2") as GameScene
```

should be

```
  var level2 = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("level2") as GameScene
```

This should also fix the "Swift dynamic cast failed" error.